# Primary occupation for the US visa - student or full-time employee?, I'm both

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, applications, study

I have been a full-time software developer working for a private company for the last 2.8 years, I'm also a college student in the middle of an academic grading term (I study at night).

I'm filing DS-160, there is an option for "STUDENT" or "COMPUTER SCIENCE" as the main occupation and I don't know what to choose in "Work / Education / Training" section of the form. I understand that both are responsibilities that show strong ties to my native country (DR).

If I choose STUDENT, then I don't have a way to specify my current job and income, if I choose EMPLOYEED then I don't have a way to explay I'm in the middle of my grading term at college.

I need help.

Comment: Here in the US, a "study at night" set up is usually indicative of a part time degree program such that the primary occupation is the software developer role. I'm doing something similar for a graduate degree, and this is how I would fill such an application. I'm not familiar with the DS-160 form -- is there anywhere like a free form entry where you can mention that you are also pursuing a degree at the same time? For sure it would strengthen your application to mention both the employment and schooling.

Comment: I think you are right, my primary occupation is my full-time job, I guess that's the way to go. Sad that there is no way to specify my current "studying" situation. Thanks!

Comment: There is only one entry to specify main occupation, either you can select STUDENT and detail college info or you can select the area of profession and detail your job info.

Comment: Which one did you select, what was the outcome?

Answer (score 3):

You can choose 'student' then explain your activities for example, I'm an international student entitled to 20hours in term time and full time during holidays. Also, I attend classes 3x a week as well as volunteer as a retail assistant at Zara retail outlet

Comment: Volunteer means unpaid. Presumably you're paid for being a retail assistant!